# Use jq to "clear" values

Tags: json, jq

Using arbitrary [json](/questions/tagged/json) with [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) how can I print a version with the "values" cleared to "empty". (sorry if I am butchering the terminology).

So basically from this:

```
{
  "colors": [
    {
      "color": "black",
      "category": "hue",
      "type": "primary",
      "code": {
        "rgba": [255,255,255,1],
        "hex": "#000"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "colors": [
    {
      "color": "",
      "category": "",
      "type": "",
      "code": {
        "rgba": ,
        "hex": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Or this:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/PaiEDiVxOyCWelLPuuwa9LKz3Gk\"",
  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
  "regionCode": "KE",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 4249,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/2dIR9BTfr7QphpBuY3hPU-h5u-4\"",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "IirngItQuVs"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To this (or a rough equivalent):

```
{
  "kind": "",
  "etag": "",
  "nextPageToken": "",
  "regionCode": "",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": ,
    "resultsPerPage":
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "",
      "etag": "",
      "id": {
        "kind": "",
        "videoId": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `  "rgba": ,` is invalid. Do you mean `null` or an array of nulls or s.t. else?

Comment: @peak Yeah, the converted portions from above were more of an estimate about what the results might look like. Ultimately the accepted solution provided below does exactly what I wanted despite my rough attempt to describe it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get paths to non-iterable values at any level in the input using `paths(scalars)`, and update them with *empty* values using `reduce` and `setpath`-`getpath` built-ins.

```
{null: null, boolean: false, number: 0, string: ""} as $e
| reduce paths(scalars) as $p (.; setpath($p; $e[getpath($p)|type])
```

<sup>[demo at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/72RkJXj2h3)</sup>